# Разбить строку не удаляя разделители

Tags: php

Добрый день. 
Нужно разбить строку на массив при этом сохранить разделитель
Как такое реализовать с explode еще не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста

Кусочек кода

```
    $picture = implode(xml2array($category->picture));
    $picture = explode("https",$picture);

    $yml_offer['picture'] = '';
    foreach ($picture as $pictures){
        $yml_offer['picture'].= $pictures.',';
    }
```

Comment: explode так не умеет. Самое простое - обработать результат работы explode и добавить разделитель ко всем элементам итогового массива, кроме последнего (или первого? если разделитель должен остаться в начале, а не в конце).

Answer (score 4):

```
$delimiter = ",";
$fakeDelimiter = "|";
$myString = str_replace($delimiter, $delimiter.$fakeDelimiter, $myString);
$result = explode($fakeDelimiter, $myString);
```

Ну либо `$fakeDelimiter.$delimiter`, если разделитель надо оставлять в начале следующего элемента.

Answer (score 1):

```
$picture=preg_split("/(?=https)/",$picture,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[Пример на ideone](https://ideone.com/jnVIlY)